# How are comments handled for re-opened questions?

Tags: support

I left a comment (as did several others) on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201460/how-do-i-download-buy-music). It deals with downloading music and copyright, both controversial subjects.

Looking at its [revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/201460/revisions), I see it was closed, then re-opened by a moderator. Nearly all the comments are removed, not just mine.

**Are comments routinely deleted when re-opening questions? Or, was there an issue with the particular comments left by myself and others?**

Positive or negative feedback are welcome. I don't know if there was a problem with our comments that should be avoided in the future, or if it is standard practice to delete most comments when re-opening.

Comment: Just for the record: yes, comments are expendable and are deleted regularly. Any information you want to persist needs to be in an answer or the question body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular question, a senior member of the community had made a subtle but important change to the question that made the question distinctly answerable and no longer about "copyright".

> I have linux 12.04.1, how would I download music? >> How do I download/buy

as well as adding

> I don't know about copyright infringement, but no that's not what I want to do. I'm wanting to buy music not steal it.

The comments therefore were no longer valid for the revised question - hence removed.

The close - open action was to cancel the previous perceived "copyright" close votes.  This, though doesnt stop AU members to issue close votes if they still perceive the question to be off-topic etc.

All comments are regularly reviewed - where not relevant they are removed.

This explains my take what has happened to this question.

Comment: +1 thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: I was the one who flagged this. Basically the OP added new information, so I just moved them into the question instead of the comments. At that point the comments made no sense anymore, so I just flagged them all for removal.